# Многопоточный прогрессбар при долгой функции

Tags: qt, многопоточность, qt5

Как, не создавая отдельного класса-потомка `QObject`, можно вызвать в отдельном потоке функцию с возможностью обновлять прогрессбар?

Есть очень долгая функция с возможностью передачи callback-функции и данных:

```
typedef bool (loadProgressFunc) (int percent, void* userHandle);

bool veryLongFunc(int inputData, loadProgressFunc progress, void* userHandle);
```

Как сделать вызов этой функции в отдельном потоке, но чтобы в окне прогрессбар обновлялся?

```
static bool process(int percent, void* userHandle) {
    qDebug() << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << percent;
    MainWindow* _this = static_cast<MainWindow*>(userHandle);
    _this->testFunc(percent);
    return true;
}

void MainWindow::testFunc(int percent) {
    ui->progressBar->setValue(percent);
}

void MainWindow::startLongFunc() {
    veryLongFunc(1, process, this);
}
```

Comment: без создания класса на практике — ни как... или наследника `QObject`, или `QThread` сделать придётся... первое — предпочтительнее... если же это не практический вопрос, а головоломка, то можно сделать трубу, которая будет передавать уведомления между потоками и подвесить её на `QSocketNotifier`.

Comment: задача практическая) Значит отдельный класс, спасибо)

Comment: можно юзать банальный qApp->processEvents(); Интерфейс приморозится, но прогрессбар бежать будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Можно воспользоваться модулем [QtConcurrent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html) и функцией [QtConcurrent::run](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#run).

Чтобы модуль стал доступен его надо подключить в pro-файле:

```
QT += concurrent
```

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QProgressBar>
#include <QtConcurrent>

typedef bool (loadProgressFunc)(int percent, void* userHandle);

void veryLongFunc(int inputData, loadProgressFunc progress, void* userHandle) {
    static int i = inputData;
    while( (i += 1) < 100) {
        progress(i, userHandle);
        QThread::msleep(500); // пауза
    }
}

bool process(int percent, void* bar) {
    reinterpret_cast<QProgressBar*>(bar)->setValue(percent);
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QProgressBar bar;
    QtConcurrent::run(veryLongFunc, 0, (loadProgressFunc*)process, &bar);
    bar.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: насколько законно обращаться к главному окну напрямую из другого потока?

Comment: @KtoTo вполне законно, если только не менять родителя данного виджета на другого, созданного в другом потоке (в Qt получите сообщение об ошибке). В принципе, механизм signal-slot при классическом использовании QThread тоже можно напрямую соединить со слотом в каком-нибудь виджете, то есть фактически сделать прямой вызов, например через Qt::DirectConnection в последнем поле QObject::connect. Так что все ок :)